# Adjusting layout of text/bullets within beamer

Tags: beamer

This is a rather simple question, but I've been having trouble.

My simplest goal is to be able to easily adjust my frame environment so that its displays like this:

**First-line -- I want this BOLD**

- Bullet one
- Bullet two

The below code works fine... however, I'd like to avoid typing textbf{} at the beginning of each line and just have every frame defined in this way.

```
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
   \textbf{First line -- I want this BOLD}
       \begin{itemize}
       \item Bullet one
       \item Bullet two
       \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

---

If this is easy enough to tweak, what I'd really like to do is have all of the itemizing and sub-itemizing to follow this format:

**Size 16**

- Size 14 (with circle bullet point)
- Size 14 (with circle bullet point)

  - Size 12 (with dash bullet point)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

1. To use circles in itemized lists:

   ```
   \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
   ```
2. To change the font size in `itemize`, a redefinition of `\itemize` (as implemented in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`) is needed.
3. For the other requirement (change font size and font series for the first line of text), I would suggest you to define a dedicated command. An automated solution might not be the best choice in this case, since the scope for the modification would not be clear and this could produce undesired results. Defining a dedicated environment for both the series and size changes is safer (and you won't need to type too many characters).

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
      {\def\makelabel##1{%
          {%
            \hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
          }%
        }
        \ifnum \@itemdepth =1
          \fontsize{14}{17}\selectfont%
        \else
        \ifnum \@itemdepth =2
          \fontsize{12}{14.5}\selectfont%
        \fi\fi
      }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright%
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

\newcommand\bfdc[1]{%
  {\fontsize{16}{19}\bfseries#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame title}
\bfdc{First line -- BOLD}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bullet one
       \begin{itemize}
       \item Bullet one
       \begin{itemize}
       \item Bullet one
       \item Bullet two
       \end{itemize}
       \item Bullet two
       \end{itemize}
\item Bullet two
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]